# Debugging db calls: $wpdb->insert works on test site, not on identical production site

Tags: wpdb

I have 2 sites on the same server, one is production, one is test. Test site works fine, production does not. They are pointed to unique databases. I added a new table with 5 fields to each. My $wpdb->insert on test site works fine. On production, I have tracked the error, 'wpdb_get_table_charset_failure' into wp-db.php

```
$results = $this->get_results( "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $table" );
```

On production, the $results returned is NULL which throws an error. I can execute this query manually and it works - returns descriptions of the 5 rows, same exact result on both test and production mysql databases. I'm at a loss to debug further bc I get buffering errors on print_r trying to write $this->last_result to a file and of course, debugging on a production site is problematic in general (adding debug log stmts to db calls generates MBs of text per second!)

FYI, collation is the same on both DBs and both tables. Everything else on the site works fine, I just cannot insert into this table on the production code. There is obviously something different, but I'm struggling to figure out what.

Here's the relevant code (again, same code on test site works fine):

```
global $wpdb;
$ip = getIpAddr();
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
$stored_email = array(
    'email' => $email_address,
    'ip' => $ip,
    'date_added' => $now
);
$rt = $wpdb->insert('free_users',
    $stored_email, array('%s', '%s', '%s')
);
if ($rt) {
    $email_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
} else { //error
    //TODO: Handle insert error
    debug_log("database error");
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Ok, I added the code snippet. Really hoping that someone knows of some magical way to debug wordpress specific PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Use `define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );` in your wp-config.php, then log `$wpdb->queries` to a file for your requests (based on IP, cookie...) so you don't get overwhelmed by lots of data.

Comment: I can log the query, the insert query. But the error is occurring in field checking. So the query associated with the error is the "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $table" which becomes "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `free_users`" which is a valid query in both the test and production DBs. The debugging that I can't  get is the $this->last_results which gets passed back to get_table_charset() as NULL - somehow?

Comment: do your tables have a prefix? did you by any chance use the wrong prefix?

Comment: No prefix - this is a non-wordpress table. It's separate. This code works perfectly on my test site, which is identical. I've even dumped the production db and recreated it for test site and it works there just fine. It's something very mysterious and obscure. Within the wordpress php on this parallel site, the SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM TABLE is returning null for this table. Note I have a handful of other non-wp tables and those all work fine.